# How to prove that if $A$ is an $4\times 4$ matrix, and $A^{20}=0$, then $A^4=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was told, that in this case the characteristic polynomial is $x^{20}$, and the minimal polynomial divides this,

"so it (the minimal polynomial) must be $x$, or $x^2$, or $x^3$, or $x^4$."

But i dont understand why.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is definitely *not* $x^{20}$, because it has to have degree 4.

Answer (score 2):

That's because $A$ is a root of the monomial $x^{20}$, and the minimal polynomial of $A$ has degree a most $4$, which is a divisor of any annihilator polynomial of A.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A^{20}=0$ the minimal polynomial divides $X^{20}$. Also the characteristic polynomial is of degree $4$ and the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial so the degree of minimal polynomial is $\leq 4$.
Combining these two facts you can get the result.